# Cannot run Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

This morning, I'm not able do run Eclipse Indigo whereas yesterday it was working.

I receive this message :

> An error has occured. See the log file E:\workspaces\sim.metadata.log

And my .log file displays :

```
!STACK 0
!MESSAGE An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.core.resources (103).
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Illegal constant pool index 7436 for method signature in class file org/eclipse/core/internal/resources/MarkerManager
...
!STACK 1
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/core/resources/IContainer
...
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseLazyStarter$TerminatingClassNotFoundException: An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.core.resources (103).
...
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in org.eclipse.core.resources.ResourcesPlugin.start() of bundle org.eclipse.core.resources.
```

I ran Eclipse with the `clean` argument but it's the same.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your eclipse crashed sometime before and is unable to restore the workspace.

You can delete .metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.snap .

Or

Try using a new workspace. Change the settings in \configuration.settings\org.eclipse.ui.ide.prefs and set SHOW_WORKSPACE_SELECTION_DIALOG to true

After that import all your projects to your workspace.

Comment: Hi, I don't have `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.snap` folder/file and my `configuration.settings\org.eclipse.ui.ide.prefs` doesn't contain `SHOW_WORKSPACE_SELECTION_DIALOG` entry. If I add it, it's the same.

Comment: I'm sorry, for Indigo is .markers, please delete this file <workspace>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.markers .

Comment: I don't have this folder. I have : .history, .projects, .root, .safetable

Comment: Then delete <workspace>/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.root/*some_number*.tree

And re-import the projects and re-assign the working sets.

Comment: I deleted my 159.tree file, launched Eclipse with the clean argument but it crashed again

Comment: I have no solutions left. Better do like Mayank said, to do the reinstall.

Answer (score 1):

Try reinstalling Eclipse. The message regarding an illegal constant pool index sounds like a broken `.class` file. Your settings and workspace should remain intact, but you may need to re-install your plugins (if any).

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you still have your workspace intact.The best and fastest option would be to reinstall eclipse and replace the new workspace with the older one.

Comment: Yes I will do that but I will need to reinstall all my plugins...sic !

Comment: You can tell a modern Eclipse to pull out plugins from another installation.  Much faster.